# With Ubuntu 19.10 I receive the error message "permission denied" when scheduled back up should occur

Tags: 19.10

I am new to Linux.  I have a new system with Ubuntu 19.10 (just upgraded) and I can not get the back up to process without the error "permission denied" occurring.  How do I set the permissions to "no" on this drive?

Comment: There are as many ways to backup as there are grains of sand on the beach. It's not clear which method you are using that is not working.

Comment: I have a dedicated drive /dev/ mounted and I am trying to use the automatic scheduling function for every week.  It attempts do do this but indicates the the back up was not successful due to "permission denied" error.  In properties under tab marked permissions  I have set create and delete files for me (owner) and access files for group as well as others.  Under security it says unknown.

Comment: Mounted drive is /dev/sdc

Comment: Explain more. What do you want to backup? Where are they? In `/home/user` dir or somewhere else? It's a one-time backup or you want to make is scheduled? If your files are in other folders than the `/home/user` folder, don't change the root permission at all! I say it 'case you said you'r new to Linux. You may destruct your system files.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is probably is not running the get update as administrator so open your terminal and run these commands;

Step 1: Fetch the updates available for your computer using apt-get update command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 2: You can then use apt-get upgrade command will upgrade the current packages

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Step 3use the distribution upgrade command.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Ubuntu, Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run this command to create the backup folder we want to store the backup file:

```
mkdir ~/backup && cd ~/backup
```

Then start your system backup with this command:

```
tar cvpjf backup.tar.bz2 --exclude=/proc4 --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys / --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/backup.tar.bz2
```

If you want to exclude more folders, you can add this option followed by the folder full path in the end of the command given above as follows:

```
--exclude=/folder
```

You can browse the folder containing the backup archive file with this command:

```
nautilus ~/backup
```

You can then recover with this command:

```
tar xvpfj backup.tar.bz2 -C /
```

or run this command (full path indicated):

```
tar xvpfj ~/backup/backup.tar.bz2 -C /
```

Comment: Those commands are good.  Can you tell me if it is normal to have an entire 1 terabyte ssd taken up by the Linux OS (Master Boot Record) and I think the the dev/ubuntu-vg root and the /dev/ubuntu-vg swap?  I have 4 drives on this and I did not partition them but I did'nt think I would need a terabyte for the OS.  I have remaining a 1 tb ssd and a 500 gb ssd and a 4tb mechanical drive.  I would rather have the OS on the 500 ssd and the rest for storage.  Is it possible to choose which drive the os is installed on?

Comment: @ThomasVanLare While installing, just plug the 500GB SSD. But anyway, while installing you can choose which device to install the OS on. I think it's OK for a home laptop to give 30GB to root (/), 2*RAM to swap, and others to `/home` directory. Your home directory is where your files are saved. Make it. Note: If you need your data on 500SSD, make sure to back them up! Then format it and make (/) dir, swap and (/home) partitions. (Another note: If you want to answer sb, make sure to mention them by `@username` format. Look at the first word of first line of my comment. There is your name)

Comment: @MohammadKholghi Thank you for your excellent response.  So 30 GB to root  /  Not sure what you mean by 2*RAM for swap.  Each partition should be 30GB?  Three partitions Master Boot Record, swap & root?  Is Master Boot in  /home?

Comment: @MohammadKholghi  Thanks for the conduct tip.

Comment: @ThomasVanLare your welcome. Look, first I have to say we don't have an MBR partition. It's installed on the root (`/`). Second, for partitioning, if you have a private laptop (home laptop), doing your daily stuff, do this: create 3 partitions. One is for root (`/`). The second is for `swap` and the third one is for `/home`. Put 30 GB for root (`/`), 2*ram for `swap` (If your ram is 4GB, put 8GB for `swap` partition), and put the remaining space for your `/home`. Before these things answer a question: do you want to dual boot your laptop? I mean if you want to have Windows and Linux together?